# Dropping a postgres database in cmdline, still seeing the database when \list

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to drop my database and create a new one through the command line.

I login using psql postgres and then do a \list, see a list of the two databases i created which i now want to delete. so i tried using a DROP DATABASE databasename;

I don't see any error while executing that statement but when i try to \list again to see if that DB are deleted, i still see that that the DB exists. Can someone please tell me why this could happen? and how to surely delete those DB.

Comment: Sounds impossible. You should get an error message if `DROP DATABASE` does not work.

Comment: At a guess you have >1 postgresql install and you dropped the database on one of them, then listed DBs on another.

Comment: Did you get a feedback `DROP DATABASE` indicating that the database was dropped? Or does psql just "sit there and says nothing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple caveats to `DROP DATABASE`:

1. It can only be executed by the database owner.
2. It cannot be executed while you or anyone else are connected to the target database.

I generally use the **dropdb** command-line tool to do this, since it's a wrapper around `DROP DATABASE` which doesn't require you to explicitly connect first. It still has the caveat that there can't be any users currently connected to the database, but it's generally quicker/easier to use.

I would recommend you try issuing a command like this:

`dropdb -h <host> -U <user> -p <port> <name of db to drop>`

Similarly, you can use the **createdb** command-line tool to create a database.

More info on `DROP DATABASE`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html

**Edit:**

Also, it is worth looking in the *Postgres* log (likely in /var/log/postgresql by default) to see if perhaps there is anything in there that wasn't surfaced in the results.

Comment: OP says they did not see any error when try to drop the database.

Comment: Right, but I think it would be instructive to see if the same holds true when using **dropdb**. Also, the Postgres doc essentially suggests using **dropdb** on the page for `DROP DATABASE`, so I think it's worth using instead in general.